# Can only upload to Apple App Store with bitcode set to yes

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, app-store-connect, application-loader

I was having some trouble uploading my Ionic Ios App to the App Store through Xcode(v 7.2).

I was constantly faced with the error: "upload failed: You are not authorized to use this service for provider XXXXXX"

After some careful problem solving I was able to resolve that I needed to have "Enable Bitcode: Yes" under my project's Target. This allowed me to upload the app through Application Loader by exporting the app with bitcode attached.

My question is in terms of my wanting to better understand what is going on under the hood here.

What difference did the enabling of bitcode make to allow the app to upload vs not having it? I tested this out to confirm and this one change was the difference in the success and failure of uploading.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What difference did the enabling of bitcode make to allow the app to upload vs not having it? I tested this out to confirm and this one change was the difference in the success and failure of uploading.

->**You don't need to Set Yes to bitcode for iOS apps**. Enabling bitcode might have simply recompiled your libraries ( above error looks like an profile error). To prove this theory, disable bitcode (Set Value to No) recompile and upload on iTunes.

Refer to this link 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html

For **iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional**. For **watchOS and tvOS apps, bitcode is required**. If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle (all targets in the project) need to include bitcode.

Comment: I uploaded few versions of my app when bitcode was enabled. Recently I'm using a SDK to connect a printer. If I keep bitcode enabled, I'm getting apple linker error with exit code 1. Because the SDK is not bitcode supported. Hence, I disabled bitcode and uploaded to itunesconnect for testflight but the new version of the app is not showing. Any suggestion in this case?